# Xamarin listview with images don't scroll smoothly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing a blog app where I placed a card in each list of items. In those cards, there are labels along with images. The problem is when listview loads it doesn't scroll smoothly with images and my images are from URI. I have also used the latest FFImageLoading plugin and still the issue is the same. Even extra problem is there, this plugin is not caching the right image.

I already searched a lot on the internet and it started to feel like that xamarin don't have any solution for this. Last hope is this question only.

My xaml page

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local1:HomeViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelcetedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" SeparatorVisibility="None"
          RowHeight="150" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" HasUnevenRows="True"  >

        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <extended:InfiniteScrollBehavior IsLoadingMore="{Binding IsBusy}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <local:CardViewTemplate />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.Footer>
            <Grid Padding="6" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
                <Grid.Triggers>
                    <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Grid.Triggers>
                <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="DeepPink" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Footer>
```

BindingContext HomeViewModel.cs

```
public HomeViewModel()
    {
        Items = new InfiniteScrollCollection<HomeDto>
        {
            OnLoadMore = async () =>
            {
                IsBusy = true;

                // load the next page
                var page = Items.Count / PageSize;

                var items = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync(page, PageSize);

                IsBusy = false;

                // return the items that need to be added
                return items;
            },
            OnCanLoadMore = () =>
            {
                return Items.Count < Convert.ToInt32(_dataService.CardDataCollection.Count);
            }
        };

        DownloadDataAsync();
    }
```

Data comes from here

```
 private void GenerateCardModel()
    {
        CardDataCollection = HomeServiceHelper.AllArticles();

        foreach(var item in CardDataCollection)
        {
            item.ImageUrl = "http://192.168.31.204:8080/" + item.ImageUrl;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<HomeDto>> GetItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        return CardDataCollection.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
```

Lastly, my frames (CardViewTemplate.xaml) which display data in listview's each cell

```
<Frame IsClippedToBounds="True"
     HasShadow="True"
     BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="5" Margin="10" >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label FontAttributes="None" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="18" 
                       FontFamily="Arial" Text="{Binding ArticleHeading, Mode = TwoWay}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="#212121"
                       MaxLines="3">
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Yellow"  WidthRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ff:CachedImage Source="{Binding  ImageUrl}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CacheType="Memory">
                </ff:CachedImage>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label FontAttributes="None" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                       FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Admin , Mode = TwoWay}" TextColor="#212121" >
                </Label>
                <Label FontAttributes="None" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                       FontSize="14" Text="{Binding LastModifiedOn , Mode = TwoWay, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" TextColor="Gray" >
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Can you post some code/xaml of your `ListView`?

Comment: @Nick can you suggest after seeing my code.

Comment: I would start by simplifying your `DataTemplate` and removing as many extra views from it as possible. There seems to be a lot of extra `StackLayout`s that could probably be replaced with the `Grid` you already have. Also, if you can get away with not setting `HasUnevenRows="True"` that alone on your listview may speeds things up enough and I'd then go from there to look into your `ff:CachedImage` issue.

Comment: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-Advanced#usage-in-listview-with-a-lot-of-elements-and-listviewcachingstrategyrecycleelement-enabled-default

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your Caching Strategy is Recycle element in Listview.

Then, to prevent the images appearing in the wrong cells, extend the custom viewcell, and change the source of your image. You can check the [official documentation](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-Advanced).

See an example:

```
public class MyCustomCell : ViewCell
{
    readonly CachedImage cachedImage = null;

    public MyCustomCell()
    {
        cachedImage = new CachedImage();
        View = cachedImage;
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        // you can also put cachedImage.Source = null; here to prevent showing old images occasionally
        cachedImage.Source = null;

        //Cast the respective model.
        var item = BindingContext as Item;

        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        cachedImage.Source = item.ImageUrl;

        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    }
}
```